# Why c =! c is true if c is boolean false?

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-logic

I don't understand why this code returns true:

```
boolean c = false;
 
c =! c;
```

isn't it comparing false boolean to false boolean? Or maybe it's assigning "NOT false" to c, which is true?

Comment: "Or maybe it's assigning "NOT false" to c, which is true?" Exactly!

Comment: I don't know why people vote down questions like that? Everybody gotta start somewhere. The guy just need an explanation of what's happening here. He maybe new to programming!

Answer (score 6):

`c =! c` (which is more readable as the equivalent `c = !c`) is assigning the negation of `c` to `c`. The value of this assignment is the new value of `c`, which could be `true` if `c` was originally `false`.

If you want to compare `c` to `!c`, it should be `c != c`.

Answer (score 5):

`c =! c;` means "assign to c the complement of its current value".

If its current value is false, then its value becomes true.

Perhaps you meant `c != c`, which is false whether `c` is true or false.

However, note that you can't write `c != c;` because that's not a valid statement: you'd need to use the expression somehow, e.g.

```
System.out.println(c != c);
```